# How to hide Jump Bar in Xcode

Tags: xcode

How to hide Jump Bar in Xcode?

> [image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, though I wish it were a setting.

Comment: Recent versions of Xcode (11, 12) have added controls to the jump bar making it even less likely that hiding it will be an option.